need to check every 2 seconds data, use of Timer blocked the main Thread
I'm trying to use a Timer to verify Data from SQL every 2 seconds. I'm trying to have a live status in my App.
For example if i click on "Start" the second person will have a message.
So i use a Timer to do this, the problem is that the Timer is blocking the Main Thread and after 20/30 seconds the Timer stop by itself.
here's my code:
Verify_User_Permission();

Function that verify the User Permission, if he has the right permission a button of "Start Daily" will appear and the Timer will begin, if someone else already click on this button the button will be hidden, and a text blinking will appear with the Storyboard Daily_Meeting_sb
private void Verify_User_Permission()
{
  if (timer_daily_meeting != null)
  {
      timer_daily_meeting.Stop();
  }

  //Verify the User Permission

if (Daily_days.Contains(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
{
   if (Daily_Meeting_Summary.Count == 0)
   {
      foreach (string Division in List_Divisions)
      {
          List<Daily_Meeting> List_Daily_Meeting = Function_Select_SQL.Get_Daily_Meeting("", Division, DateTime.Now);

          Daily_Meeting_Summary.Add(Division, (List_Daily_Meeting == null || List_Daily_Meeting[0].End_Time == (DateTime?)null ? "False" : "True"));
      }
   }

   else
    {
       List<Daily_Meeting> List_Daily_Meeting = Function_Select_SQL.Get_Daily_Meeting("", Division_Selected, DateTime.Now);

       Daily_Meeting_Summary[Division_Selected] = (List_Daily_Meeting == null || List_Daily_Meeting[0].End_Time == (DateTime?)null ? "False" : "True");
    }

    if (Daily_Meeting_Summary.Where(x => x.Value == "True").Count() != Daily_Meeting_Summary.Count)
    {
        InitTimer_Daily_Meeting();
    }
        }
}

Function to Initialize the Timer
public void InitTimer_Daily_Meeting()
{
   List <Admin_Settings> List_Admin_Settings = Function_Select_SQL.Get_Admin_Settings("Daily_Days_Setting");

   string[] Daily_days = List_Admin_Settings != null && List_Admin_Settings.Count == 1? List_Admin_Settings[0].Setting_First_Value.Split(',') : null;

   if (Daily_days.Contains(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
   {
      timer_daily_meeting = new Timer();
      timer_daily_meeting.Elapsed += Timer_daily_meeting_Elapsed;
      timer_daily_meeting.Interval = 2000; // in miliseconds
      timer_daily_meeting.AutoReset = false;
      timer_daily_meeting.Start();
   }
}

Function Elapsed of the Timer
private void Timer_daily_meeting_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     Verify_Timer_Elapsed_Time();
     Verify_User_Permission();
 }

private void Verify_Timer_Elapsed_Time()
 {
     timer_daily_meeting.Stop();

     List<Admin_Settings> List_Admin_Settings = Function_Select_SQL.Get_Admin_Settings("Daily_Duration");

     List<Daily_Meeting> List_Daily_Meeting = (Function_Select_SQL.Get_Daily_Meeting("", "", (Datagrid_Selected.Items[0] as Argo_Snowflake).Date_Created));

     if (List_Daily_Meeting != null)
     {
         foreach (Daily_Meeting Daily_Meeting in List_Daily_Meeting)
         {
            if (Daily_Meeting.End_Time == (DateTime?)null)
            {
               if (Math.Round(((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - Daily_Meeting.Start_Time)).TotalMinutes, 1) >= double.Parse(List_Admin_Settings[0].Setting_First_Value))
               {
                   Daily_Meeting.End_Time = DateTime.Now;
                   Daily_Meeting.Duration = Math.Round(((TimeSpan)(Daily_Meeting.End_Time - Daily_Meeting.Start_Time)).TotalMinutes, 1);

                   Function_Update_SQL.Update_Daily_Meeting(Daily_Meeting);

                   Daily_Meeting_Summary[Daily_Meeting.Division] = "True";
               }
             }
          }
     }

Thank you for your help.
Edit:
Use of Threading.Timer :
private System.Threading.Timer m_objTimer;
private bool m_blnStarted;
private readonly int m_intTickMs = 1000;
private object m_objLockObject = new object();

m_objTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, m_objTimer, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
Start();

public void Start()
{
   if (!m_blnStarted)
   {
      lock (m_objLockObject)
      {
         if (!m_blnStarted) //double check after lock to be thread safe
         {
           m_blnStarted = true;

           //Make it start in 'm_intTickMs' milliseconds, 
           //but don't auto callback when it's done (Timeout.Infinite)
           m_objTimer.Change(m_intTickMs, Timeout.Infinite);
         }
      }
   }
}

public void Stop()
{
   lock (m_objLockObject)
   {
      m_blnStarted = false;
   }
 }

private void callback(object state)
{
   List<Admin_Settings> List_Admin_Settings = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke<Task<List<Admin_Settings>>>(() => Get_Admin_Setting("Daily_Duration")).Result as List<Admin_Settings>;

   List<Daily_Meeting> List_Daily_Meeting = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke<Task<List<Daily_Meeting>>>(() => Get_Daily_Meeting("", (Datagrid_Selected.Items[0] as Argo_Snowflake).Date_Created)).Result as List<Daily_Meeting>;

 Verify_User_Permission();

 Thread.Sleep(1500);

 //When your code has finished running, wait 'm_intTickMs' milliseconds
        //and call the callback method again, 
        //but don't auto callback (Timeout.Infinite)
        //m_objTimer.Change(m_intTickMs, Timeout.Infinite);

  if (Daily_Meeting_Summary.Where(x => x.Value == "True").Count() == Daily_Meeting_Summary.Count)
  {
     Stop();
  }

   else
   {
       m_objTimer.Change(m_intTickMs, Timeout.Infinite);
   }
}

I change the calling of the SQL query to Dispatcher.Invoke
private void Verify_User_Permission()
{
  //Verify the User Permission
  List<Admin_Settings> List_Admin_Settings = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke<Task<List<Admin_Settings>>>(() => Get_Admin_Setting("Daily_Days_Setting")).Result as List<Admin_Settings>;

}

public async Task<List<Admin_Settings>> Get_Admin_Setting(string Setting)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    List<Admin_Settings> List_Admin_Settings = null;

    if (Setting == "Daily_Duration")
    {
       List_Admin_Settings = Function_Select_SQL.Get_Admin_Settings("Daily_Duration");
    }

    else if (Setting == "Daily_Days_Setting")
    {
       List_Admin_Settings = Function_Select_SQL.Get_Admin_Settings("Daily_Days_Setting");
    }

    return List_Admin_Settings;

}

(Unrelated) Consider C# naming conventions.

I'd also recommend to move away from active polling. Polling is fine to get an initial state. But from then on, I'd recommend to have state changes pushed to the clients. For example using something like SignalR or whatever would be canonical for the platform in use (which I guess is WinForms?).

There's really far too much code there for us to diagnose just by looking at it. You need to do some proper investigation. Start with an empty event handler and then build it up bit by bit until you see the problem occur. You then have a pretty good idea of the source.

You "verify" the user when they log in (e.g. gets a "can press button" "privilege"). If the button was already pressed, don't let anyone press it. The "verification" process can then be decoupled from your real question.

@Fildor - I forgot to add in the Tag, it's WPF not Winforms

@jmcilhinney - I thought it's better to show all the code, i remove some of it. The problem is i thing that the Timer is running on the same Thread, so the Main Thread is blocked because of the every 2 seconds verification.

@GerrySchmitz - Yes that's what i did, when the button is already pressed, no one can pressed again because the button is hidden for other.

The timer won't block the UI - the slow code in the handler does. The unconventional code means we can't even guess what Function_Select_SQL.Get_Daily_Meeting or Function_Select_SQL.Get_Admin_Settings do, or why there are 2 SQL queries and loops, instead of a single one that JOINs the tables and returns just 1 or 0 if the conditions match. If the list of divisions comes from the database there's no need for List_Divisions. If it's user-selectable, there are ways to pass multiple values as parameters, even as a WHERE ... ID IN (@id1, @id2, @id3...) clause

The Tick event of a WinForms Timer or WPF DispatcherTimer is raised on the UI thread. The Elapsed event of a system Timer is NOT raised on the UI thread UNLESS you set the SynchronizingObject property, which you are not. Some people immediately invoke a method on the UI thread, which you are not. The usual suspects are not to blame.

The timer likely stops working since you are recreating the timer on every event, without ever disposing it, eventually running out of some internal resource. You should only be creating one timer, but you can start/stop it whenever you wish. You should also ensure any timers you create are disposed.
The blocking problem is not due to the timer, but your sql query. The Windowns.Forms.Timer will by design raise the event on the UI thread. So you need to ensure that whatever you run in that event is fast enough to not cause any problems.
If you cannot do this you need to to use either an asynchronous query or a background thread. There are several possible ways to do this, for example:

Simply changing the query to an asynchronous variant and await the result is likely the easiest.
Use Task.Run to run your query, and await the result
Changing to another timer, like Threading.Timer, that invokes the events on a background thread. But then you need to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to run any code to update the UI. Threading.Timer.Change give fine control about when the timer should elapse, but require some manual calculations.
Use a periodic timer together with an async query. This might be the easiest way to ensure there are no concurrent queries or UI issues with threading etc.

I'm not sure exactly how you are making your queries, but I would expect any competent database to support asynchronous queries by now. In any case you need to consider how you want your timing to work. Should it run one query every two seconds? Are queries allowed to overlap? Do you want a two second delay between the end of one query and the start of the next?
I would also recommend doing some profiling to figure out why this takes noticeable amount of time. Perhaps you need some index in the database, or there is something else unexpected that wastes time.

Thank you for your answer. I removed all my sql queries by putting a constant value, and the problem is the same.
I'm using a System.Timers.Timer; not a Windowns.Forms.Timer.

@dadou then you are most likely updating UI controls from a non UI thread, and that is not allowed. See the point about Threading.Timer & Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

I change my Timer to Threading.Timer it's better but the main thread is still freezing every 3/4 seconds i will edit my first post with updated code

I also change the calling of the SQl query to Dispatcher.Invoke see code in the first post. Thank you

@dadou Timers.Timer is just a wrapper around Threading.Timer, they behave the same, just with a different API. But if you are going to run everything on the UI thread you might as well use a UI-timer, for wpf that would be DispatchTimer. And you should probably avoid Thread.Sleep, that is what timers are for!
